# change password control validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using change password wizard to change the password. Is there any method to check whether the entered password and new password are same and if they are same then display an error message? I tried using code but it gives error message and also gives a success message saying that the password has been changed. Is it possible to put some compare validator to check these values?

Comment: With out posting the code which you have written how can we tell what's the wrong in your code?

Comment: standard change password control has validation to compare between new password and confirm new password. but not between current password and new password

Comment: You can put Compare validator in inbuilt-logincontrol after converting into template
it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Instead of using change password template, i used the code

```
protected void ChangePassword1_ChangedPassword(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ChangePassword1.CurrentPassword == ChangePassword1.NewPassword)
        {
            Response.Redirect("ChangePassword.aspx");

        }
        //Label1.Text = "current and new passwords should not match";        
        Label1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Initially lable1 was enter different current and new passwords.

Answer (score 2):

Add one more validator on the your change password webpage.
try the following validator:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1"
     runat="server"
     ControlToCompare="NewPassword" // ID of your new password field
     ControlToValidate="CurrentPassword"  //ID of  current password field
     ErrorMessage="You should enter different password." 
     ForeColor="Red">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: I tried using ur code. It is giving error like "Unable to find control id 'NewPassword' referenced by the 'ControlToCompare' property of 'CompareValidator1'."

Comment: @user662417: you shouldn't use like NewPassword, you should use the id of the feilds that you have

Comment: You should replace "New Password" with your control id. It is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you creating your own control,

```
 1. check the current user who is logged in
 2. when user try to change the password, probably a button click
    get the users unique id and match the new password and old password.
 3. If password match return an error, update the database with new password otherwise
```

Comment: I'm not creating my own control. I'm using the changepassword wizard

Answer (score 0):

Try

asp:CompareValidator

with Operator "property = NotEqual"

this should work

Answer (score 0):

You should have two text boxes, let's say `txtNewPassword` and `txtRePass`. This will do the job, and as seen below the built in `<asp:CompareValidator>` will do the job.
But if you also want an extra validation you can also add `Validation Group = ""`

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="Comp1" ControlToValidate="txtNewPassword" ControlToCompare="txtRePass" Text="Password mismatch" Font-Size="11px" ForeColor="Red"/>`
```